# CRUD in Hibernate with one-to-many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three entities and three tables in database with their relation:

```
 Class person {

 int id;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 List<Comment> comments;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 List<CellPhone> cellPhones;

 }

 Class Comment {

 String content;    

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "id")
 Person person;

 }

 Class CellPhone {

 String mark;    

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "id")
 Person person;

 }
```

Does Hibernate support me to do something like that ?

- Insert a new person, it automatically inserts into CellPhone and Comment, not insert by every entity.
- Delete a person with given id, then automatic delete CellPhone and Comment with their relation by id of person ?
- Let's give a person id, it gets person with all Comments and CellPhones ?
- Update something in Comment and CellPhone of a person, and save a person, it will save CellPhone and Comment automatically ?

In general, I just want to set/get CellPhone and Comment for person object, and then call getPerson(person), save(person), or delete(person) ect without get(comment), save(comment) or delete(cellPhone)..

Please help me to clarify it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried saving Person with other attributes(comment,cellphone) populated?If you try doing it, you should have the answer to it anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes to all of your questions.

Specifically, for questions 1, 2, and 4 take a look at Hibernate cascading:

1. [Hibernate Documentation on cascading](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades)
2. [Mkyong Article on cascading](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/)

For question 3, Hibernate will automatically fetch the other entities once you request them (by calling their get method).

Answer (score 2):

Have you look into CascadeType? [Here](http://webarch.kuzeko.com/2011/11/hibernate-understanding-cascade-types/) is a tutorial on this subject. HTH

Comment: Cascade that I need. Thanks vic.